# vectorization of for-loops with if-conditions gets slower

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, for-loop, vectorization

I have one for-loop that I'm working on vectorizing it. The problem is, once vectorized, the code is 3 times slower.
The original code, which is part of a thermodynamic algorithm, is:

```
Matrix=rand(10,10,20);
someMatrix=rand(50);
m=5; n=6; CONSTj=9; CONSTk=10; maxGrid=5;
Total=0;

for var=0:maxGrid
    Factor=1;
    p=CONSTj-var;
    q=CONSTk-var;

    if p>=1 && q>=1
        Factor=Matrix(n,m,p)*Matrix(m,n,q);
    elseif p>=1 && q<1
        Factor=Matrix(n,m,p);
    elseif p<1 && q>=1
        Factor=Matrix(m,n,q);
    end

    Total=Total+Factor*(someMatrix(m)^var);
end
```

I vectorized it into:

```
Matrix=rand(10,10,20);
someMatrix=rand(50);
m=5; n=6; CONSTj=9; CONSTk=10; maxGrid=5;

var=(0:maxGrid)';
Factor=ones(maxGrid+1,1);
tempoJ=zeros(maxGrid+1,1);
tempoK=zeros(maxGrid+1,1);
p=CONSTj-var;
q=CONSTk-var;

index1 = find(p>=1 & q>=1);
index2 = find(p>=1 & q<1 );
index3 = find(p<1  & q>=1);

tempoJ(index1)=squeeze(Matrix(n,m,p(index1)));
tempoJ(index2)=squeeze(Matrix(n,m,p(index2)));
tempoK(index1)=squeeze(Matrix(m,n,q(index1)));
tempoK(index3)=squeeze(Matrix(m,n,q(index3)));

Factor(index1)=tempoJ(index1).*tempoK(index1);
Factor(index2)=tempoJ(index2);
Factor(index3)=tempoK(index3);

Total=Factor.*(someMatrix(m).^var);
Total=sum(Total);
```

The profiler says that *find*, *squeeze* and *sum* are the functions that consume the most time. I believe that something can be done to get the information from the if-statement but I can't find a simpler way without altering the indices.

Comment: You probably don't need `find` - you can use a boolean vector to index.

Comment: Also I don't think you need `squeeze` either... but I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried this with a few different size data sets and I agreed the vectorization you have there looks to take roughly 50% longer to run.  I imagine this is due to the code within the `squeeze` and `find` functions particularly.  Unless you anticipate having extremely large amount of data to loop through I'd stick with what you have in the first option.

Comment: @mutzmatron do you have any ideas/suggestions to avoid using `find` or `squeeze`?

Comment: @BenA.- Yes - It seems to me you can simply remove them! At least removing `find` will give you boolean vectors of the same length as `p` and `q` which can be used to index any other vectors of the same length. As for removing `squeeze`, I think that the assignment will flow the elements indexed in the multidimensional matrix into the corresponding elements in the vector automatically without the need to "squeeze" the Matrix into a vector first!

Comment: @mutzmatron: Sometimes the values p and q are equal to zeros, that's why I'm using `find` before `squeeze` to construct TempoJ and TempoK. these two vectors are of course temporary and are only there to constitute the final vector **Factor** upon the three conditions.

Comment: @workson: You don't need `find` to do that.  Just say `index1 = p >= 1 & q >= 1`.

Comment: While I would go with @sfstewman 's answer - as mentioned above if you  still decide to vectorize, removing `find` and `squeeze` should speed up the vectorized code to at least the same speed as the original function. You can also remove your temporary variables...

Comment: I'm late to the discussion, but `squeeze` can usually be replaced with `permute`. I know `squeeze` could have been eliminated entirely in this case, but think of this as a remark in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not actually vectorize this code.  Recent versions of Matlab have an excellent JIT compiler, and vectorizing code does not have the same performance improvements that it did in older versions.

The original code is much easier to understand and maintain.  If you absolutely need performance, I would look into writing a MEX function (in C) for this.

However, if you're set on vectorizing the code, I would eliminate the unnecessary `find` and `squeeze` calls (as @mutzmatron has suggested).  Replace:

```
index1 = find(p>=1 & q>=1);
index2 = find(p>=1 & q<1 );
index3 = find(p<1  & q>=1);

tempoJ(index1)=squeeze(Matrix(n,m,p(index1)));
tempoJ(index2)=squeeze(Matrix(n,m,p(index2)));
tempoK(index1)=squeeze(Matrix(m,n,q(index1)));
tempoK(index3)=squeeze(Matrix(m,n,q(index3)));
```

with:

```
p_gt1 = p >= 1;
q_gt1 = q >= 1;

index1 =  p_gt1 &  q_gt1;
index2 =  p_gt1 & ~q_gt1;
index3 = ~p_gt1 &  q_gt1;

tempoJ(index1)=Matrix(n,m,p(index1));
tempoJ(index2)=Matrix(n,m,p(index2));
tempoK(index1)=Matrix(m,n,q(index1));
tempoK(index3)=Matrix(m,n,q(index3));
```

There's no need to `squeeze`.  The RHS of the lines with `squeeze` have the same number of elements as the LHS, so Matlab happily maps them one-to-one, and fills this in.

Even with this improvement, the vectorized code is still a bit slower than your original for loop.  I timed each using [`TIMEIT`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798):

```
% 'foo'     your original for loop
% 'foo_v0'  the original vector code, with find and squeeze
% 'foo_v'   the modified vector code, without find/squeeze

>> timeit(@()foo(Matrix,someMatrix))
ans =
   1.1482e-05

>> timeit(@()foo_v(Matrix,someMatrix))
ans =
   2.8039e-05

>> timeit(@()foo_v0(Matrix,someMatrix))
ans =
   1.3256e-04
```

Admittedly, this is code you've simplified to explain the problem; you may get different results on your actual problem.  However, be aware that Matlab has gotten smarter about compiling code, so vectorization no longer produces the speed increases that it used to.

Comment: You're right. The problem is much more complex and the `for-loop` in my original code is nested inside 5 other for-loops! In the real problem, the lines inside this small `for-loop` can run up to 5 million times that's why every single improvement can help a lot at the end, but apparently nothing can be done at least with Matlab. I heard a lot about vectorization in Matlab, but apparentlu it's for older versions not for Matlab 2012 in my case...

Comment: It's possible that `bsxfun` or `arrayfun` would help, but I doubt it.  The JIT is pretty decent.  The two things that I would think about are: (a) look at your overall strategy and see if there's a higher-level optimization available, and (b) think about converting the entire inner loop into a MEX function.  Move the loop, not its contents, so you don't have to pay the dispatch cost.  When done properly, MEX functions can really help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't an answer but there isn't enough room in the comments for me to type it all out.

Here is the test code that I used.  Based off of what the OP provided.  Note that I upped the `maxGrid` to 15 so there would be some negative values in `p` and `q`.  I also increased the size of the other matrices.  I removed the `find` and the `squeeze` function calls as well.

The resulting output was this:

```
Elapsed time is 0.078117 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.096412 seconds.
```

Ultimately this indicated that the first rendition of the code is running faster.

```
tic
Matrix=rand(100,100,200); 
someMatrix=rand(500); 
m=5; n=6; CONSTj=9; CONSTk=10; maxGrid=15; 
Total=0; 

for var=0:maxGrid 
    Factor=1; 
    p=CONSTj-var; 
    q=CONSTk-var; 

    if p>=1 && q>=1 
        Factor=Matrix(n,m,p)*Matrix(m,n,q); 
    elseif p>=1 && q<1 
        Factor=Matrix(n,m,p); 
    elseif p<1 && q>=1 
        Factor=Matrix(m,n,q); 
    end 

    Total=Total+Factor*(someMatrix(m)^var); 
end 
toc

tic
Matrix=rand(100,100,200); 
someMatrix=rand(500); 
m=5; n=6; CONSTj=9; CONSTk=10; maxGrid=15; 

var=(0:maxGrid)'; 
Factor=ones(maxGrid+1,1); 
tempoJ=zeros(maxGrid+1,1); 
tempoK=zeros(maxGrid+1,1); 
p=CONSTj-var; 
q=CONSTk-var; 

% index1 = find(p>=1 & q>=1); 
index1 = ((p>=1) & (q>=1));
% index2 = find(p>=1 & q<1 ); 
index2 = ((p>=1)&(q<1));
% index3 = find(p<1  & q>=1); 
index3 = ((p<1)&(q>=1));

tempoJ(index1)=(Matrix(n,m,p(index1))); 
tempoJ(index2)=(Matrix(n,m,p(index2))); 
tempoK(index1)=(Matrix(m,n,q(index1))); 
tempoK(index3)=(Matrix(m,n,q(index3))); 

Factor(index1)=tempoJ(index1).*tempoK(index1); 
Factor(index2)=tempoJ(index2); 
Factor(index3)=tempoK(index3); 

Total=Factor.*(someMatrix(m).^var); 
Total=sum(Total); 
toc
```

Comment: I just ran your code and found the second version to be faster (though admittedly not much : >> for_loop_timing_test
Elapsed time is 0.041173 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.032820 seconds.
>> for_loop_timing_test
Elapsed time is 0.035207 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.029443 seconds.
>> for_loop_timing_test
Elapsed time is 0.036293 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.028384 seconds.
>> for_loop_timing_test
Elapsed time is 0.033994 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.023902 seconds.
>> for_loop_timing_test
Elapsed time is 0.036123 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.028443 seconds.
>>

Comment: Odd.  Might just be different system specs.  I just ran a group of ten runs.  The mean for the first test set was `0.0797` and the mean for the second was `0.0805` so they're right on par with eachother.  Across 1000 runs it was a mean of `0.0879` for the first method and `0.0875` for the second.

Comment: Friends, you need to do longer runs to beat myriad system latency issues and present ranges or stdev and not just the mean.  You can't control latencies butvyou can amortize them into insignificance.